# Chef Mount must be root to use options

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have the following mount command as part of my recipe. I am needing this to run as root, because I get an error message that only root can use options. Thanks for the help in adavance.

```
mount mounted_dir do
  action :mount
  fstype 'cifs'
  device '//192.168.0.100/Users/rcondron/Desktop/smart-mobile-images'
  enabled node['smart-mobile']['share']['mount_share']
  options "username=testuser,password=testpwd,domain=domain,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=0"
end
```

Comment: Under answer you're talking about `omnibus-ctl`, please detail what you're doing. And maybe include the error log...

Answer (score 2):

You need to run Chef itself as root then.

The `mount` command is run as whatever user `chef-client` or `chef-solo` is running as, if you get an error that says it isn't root then I would suspect something is wrong with how you are running Chef.

Comment: I am using sudo and it gets ran from omnibus reconfigure I have tried changing to my root user with no change in results.

Comment: I think the problem is with omnibus-ctl... I will dig deeper and confirm.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15062898)

Comment: The `mount` command is run as whatever user `chef-client` or `chef-solo` is running as, if you get an error that says it isn't root then I would suspect something is wrong with how you are running Chef.

Comment: @pczeus Sadly, as the question actually stand, this is the only possible answer.